# Ve and vis pronouns and possessives in a book

Tags: pronouns, possessive-pronouns

I'm reading "On the steel breeze" by Alistar Reynolds. For a character named Travertine, he uses "ve" instead of "he" and "vis" instead of "his". 
This is a passage using "ve":

> Travertine's a pretty divisive figure. **Ve's** a friend of mine... When **ve** was last in trouble..."

and this is using "vis"

> Travertine examined **vis** fingers.

Is this some kind of formal treatment? or the writer made it up? I can't find any info about this.

Comment: Ve and Vis are not standard English. See https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86150/why-does-travertine-have-vis-own-pronouns-in-on-the-steel-breeze

Comment: The writer made it up - and it is almost certainly indicates a (fictional) other gender. Ann Leckie in her novel _Provenance_ has a third gender, referred to as _neman_ (plural _nemen_, pronouns _e_, _em_, _eir_. Also _nuncle_, the neman sibling of a parent).

Comment: Germany today (1.1.2019) introduced an intersex **divers** (or non-binary) gender option for birth certificates and other official documents. https://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/europe/germany-third-gender-identiy-official-records-diverse-binary-a8494766.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ve and vis are not standard pronouns in English. The author is using them in a science fiction context for a genderless being (not male or female). There have been numerous proposals for genderless pronouns in English. This (or one like this) had been made before the book was written. It's not certain whether the author was using this proposal or made it up independently. None of the proposals for new pronouns has been adopted by a significant number of people.

Unless someone asks you to use specific pronouns, learners should use the standard he/she::his/her pronoun system for people whose gender is known.